# Sum of ArrayList in a method

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to coding. My task is to get a total duration of all tracks in a playlist (in seconds). There is an accessor method called getDur in another class. There is also toString method that converts everything into seconds. This is my code.

```
private ArrayList<Track> tracksN;

public int getDurTotal()
{
    for (Track b: tracksN)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<tracksN.size();i++)
        {
            sum += tracks.get(getDur(i));
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

However, I'm getting an error message that says "method getDur in class PlayList cannot be applied to given type. Required: no arguments; Found: int; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length".

Comment: I think this is **Java** and not `javascript`

Comment: You want to compute a single sum. Yet, your sum variable is declared and set to 0 inside the for loop. So it's set to 0 at each iteration. What you want to add to the sum is the duration of the current track. The current track is in the variable (badly) named `b`. You don't seen a for loop inside a for loop. A single loop is sufficient: for each current rack in the track list, add the current track's duration to sum.

Comment: Welcome to coding! Tip: It's generally easier to understand what you've written if you spell out entire words rather than stopping partway through - for example, "duration" instead of "dur".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is iterating over the track list twice. One of the for loops needs to go. Either:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tracksN.size(); i++) {
   Track track = tracksN.get(i);
   sum += track.getDur();
}
```

Or

```
int sum = 0;
for (Track track : tracksN) {
   sum += track.getDur();
}
```

Between these two approaches, the second approach is better as it will work correctly (with good performance) with all List<> types, not just with ArrayList<>. It's also simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the track from the list, then call `getDur` on that. Try this:

```
private ArrayList<Track> tracksN;

public int getDurTotal()
{
    for (Track b: tracksN)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<tracksN.size();i++)
        {
            sum += getDur(tracks.get(i));
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that is in the error itself; read it again.  **PlayList cannot be applied to given type. Required: no arguments**

Meaning you called `getDur(i)` with argument `i`.

But if you can scroll through your code and find the method `getDur` doesn't need any parameter.

I bet it just looks something like `getDur(){` or something and it's return type I assume is `int`.

So if you can show the code for you class `PlayList` maybe someone can help you implement you code properly.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to use one for loop

```
int sum = 0;
for (Track track : tracksN)
{
  sum += track.getDur();
}
return sum;
```